# How does the CLT justify statistical models which are not modeling our data as a sum of random variables?

Tags: probability, statistical-inference, central-limit-theorem

Wikipedia says (emphasis mine):

> The Central Limit Theorem states "that, in some situations, when independent random variables are added, their properly normalized sum tends toward a normal distribution even if the original variables themselves are not normally distributed. **The theorem is a key concept in probability theory because it implies that probabilistic and statistical methods that work for normal distributions can be applicable to many problems involving other types of distributions.**

Now the CLT says something about the sum of independent random variables:

$$
X = X_1 + X_2 + \dots X_n
$$

where $X_i$ is the $i$th draw of a random variable. But the statistical models I am familiar with do not model the sum of random variables; they model the random variable directly.

For example, factor analysis models a random variable $\textbf{x}$ as

$$
\textbf{x} \sim \mathcal{N}(\textbf{0}, \Lambda \Lambda^{\top} + \Psi)
$$

(It does not matter what $\Lambda$ and $\Psi$ are; only that $\textbf{x}$ is modeled as Gaussian.) And this modeling assumption is justified using the CLT (see [A Unifying Review of Linear Gaussian Models](http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/zoubin/papers/lds.pdf), footnote on page 2). But aren't we modeling $\textbf{x}$, not the sum of $\textbf{x}$?

In summary: **How does the CLT justify statistical models which are not modeling our data as a sum of random variables?**

Comment: It doesn't, but many processes turn out to be a sum of other ones at a deeper level. In the case of your footnote, the variable of interest is *noise*, and noise is formed when there is interference (read: a sum) of many different external sources.

Comment: I see. This makes a lot of sense. It's too lengthy for a comment, but it explains a few other things in that paper as well. Basically, the latent variable in factor analysis—which is typically denoted $\textbf{z} \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$—is actually a constant with additive Gaussian noise as well.